# Creating a new list based on lists of tuples

Tags: python, list

Let's assume there is a list of tuples:

```
for something in x.something()
    print(something)
```

and it returns

```
('a', 'b')
('c', 'd')
('e', 'f')
('g', 'h')
('i', 'j')
```

And I have created two other lists containing certain elements from the x.something():

```
y = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
z = [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```

So I want to assign the tuples from x.something() to a new list based on y and z by

```
newlist = []
for something in x.something():
    if something in 'y':
        newlist.append('color1')
    elif something in 'z':
        newlist.append('color2')
    else:
        newlist.append('color3')
```

What I would like to have is the newlist looks like:

```
['color1', 'color1', 'color2', 'color2', 'color3']
```

But I've got

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

What went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: do you mean `something == "y"` or is y a list we dont know about?

Comment: they still wouldnt get that output, since theres not a single value of "y" or "z" in the values they have showed us

Comment: Hi Ironkey! :) I tried to used x.something() to make the story shorter but it might be a bad idea. It is actually g.edges() from the Networkx-package, and "something" is actually the edges connecting between two nodes. So in this example there are 5 edges between a and b, c and d, e and f, etc. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get `if something in y` instead of `if something in 'y'` because they are two seperate lists, not strings:

```
newlist = []
for something in x.something():
    if something in y:
        newlist.append('color1')
    elif something in z:
        newlist.append('color2')
    else:
        newlist.append('color3')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wasif, your comment solved my problem :) that was exactly what went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
t = [('a', 'b'),
('c', 'd'),
('e', 'f'),
('g', 'h'),
('i', 'j')]

y = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
z = [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
new_list = []
for x in t:
    if x in y:
        new_list.append('color1')
    elif x in z:
        new_list.append('color2')
    else:
        new_list.append('color3')
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['color1', 'color1', 'color2', 'color2', 'color3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes from `if something in 'y'` because it assumes that you're checking if `something` is in the string `'y'`. Same for `z`.